# Macro to be enabled when I click on different captions

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need your help to set up below macro in PowerPoint to be enabled when I click on specific caption

For example

I want to add 5 different captions/shapes Monday, Tuesday Wednesday, Thursday,Friday

Currently I add two shapes - and + near TeamBarometer caption and I can control this which is great but I need when I click on Monday to work for Monday , when I click on Tuesday to work only for Tuesday etc

I don't have much experience and I really need your support

```
Sub TeamBarometer_minus ()
TeamBarometer.Caption = (TeamBarometer.Caption) -1
End Sub

Sub TeamBarometer_plus ()
TeamBarometer.Caption = (TeamBarometer.Caption) +1
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to capture an event like SlideSelectionChanged. Here's how to use events in VBA: http://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00004_Make_your_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint_respond_to_events.htm Here's a current list of PowerPoint events: https://www.officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html Another events tutorial page: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=327

Comment: Are the captions/shapes basic text boxes/rectangles or the like? And are you on Mac or PC?  Depending on the answer to that, I might be able to give you a bit of skeleton code that'd do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for help I try my best .  I am on Pc  my caption is   an Label (Active X control ) and my shapes which I am using are - and + and from Monday to Friday I didn't chose yet can be anything texbox , shape ,label control .I still don't know what I can use to work